# How to get a route from a controller/method name in Rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

As exemple I have a routes.rb file like this one

```
FilePicker::Application.routes.draw do

  match "youtube/search/videos/:query(/:maxResults)", :to => "Youtube#youtubeVideos", :via => :get
  match "youtube/searchWithToken/:query/:token(/:maxResults)", :to => "Youtube#youtubeTokenPageVideos", :via => :get

  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

And I would like to be able, by using the combination controller/action, to get the route back.
Something like that:

```
class YoutubeController < ApplicationController

    def initialize
        @routeA = getRoute 'Youtube', 'youtubeVideos'
        puts @routeA #=> youtube/search/videos
    end

    def youtubeVideos
        @routeB = getRoute 'Youtube', 'youtubeTokenPageVideos'
        puts @routeB #=> youtube/searchWithToken
    end
    def youtubeTokenPageVideos
        ...
    end
end
```

Is this possible ?

### EDIT

I don't think `request.path` is the solution since it would give me the actual path used. as example, the actions `youtubeVideos` has been called, from here, how can i dynamically get the path for the action `youtubeTokenPageVideos` ? (I edited the above example as well)

Comment: Why won't you use `request.path`?
BTW conventions. Method names should be with underscore, `like_this`. Use `before_filter` instead of `initialize`.

Comment: @MarekLipa, I edited my answer about `request.path`. About before_filter, I have no idea how to use it instead of initialize. I actually use initialize to create the variables I will need in different methods of my controller. If possible could you give me an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it for example in this way:

```
class YoutubeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_route

  def youtube_videos
    #some_code
  end

  def youtube_token_page_videos
    #some_code
  end

  private

  def set_route
    @route = url_for(:controller => :youtube,
                     :action => :youtube_videos,
                     :query => 'Some query')
  end
end
```

You should also modify your routes to match this example. Thanks to usage of `before_filter`, you have `@route` variable set in every action of this controller.

You can also name your routes, like in following example:

```
#routes.rb
 match "youtube/search/videos/:query(/:maxResults)", :to => "Youtube#youtube_videos", :via => :get, :as => :youtube_videos
```

If you do this, you just need to call `youtube_videos_path` with appropriate parameters in your controller/view to get your path.

Comment: That helped me a lot!
I added :only_path to you answer since what i need is `youtube/search/videos` and not the complete `http://..../`.
Also since i only want the url without the parameters in order to reuse it added `.chop[1..-1]` to remove the remaining `/` in the beginning and in the end.

Comment: Instead of reusing variable, you can call method every time it's necessary - I edited my answer to make it simplier.

Comment: That last part where you say you can name routes in the example you have given, works fine in year 2022.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `url_for(:controller => "youtube_controller", :action => "youtubeTokenPageVideos)`. Also, i have some comments about ruby, rails and conventions, hope you don't mind:

In ruby are it a convention to name classes and modules with CamelCase (like you do: `class YoutubeController`), but methods should be snake_case like `def youtube_token_page_videos`.

Also you should never use `initialize` in a controller. I would encourage you to learn more about some of Rails' basics like how controllers works. A good place to start is the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html. Here you can learn about eg. before filters. Im not sure how experienced you are in Rails, in general, but http://codeschool.com have a very good free starting course for rails: http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux.

Comment: Thx man, i'm actually just starting in rails, i will give a look at your links :)